# What exactly is $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\theta]/\mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I was self-studying group theory using Nathan Jacobson's *Basic Algebra* and I can't understand what $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\theta]/\mathbb{Q})$ is and why it has group structure.

Here $\theta$ is a complex number, and $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ is the set of complex 'outputs' when $\theta$ is substituted into every rational polynomial.
I know that $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ is a vector space over the rationals, and that its basis is $\{1,\theta,\theta^2,\dots,\theta^{n-1}\}$ if the dimension is $n$.

The book defines $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\theta]/\mathbb{Q})$ as the group of automorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ to itself. However, there are several things about this I cannot understand:

1. What is the group structure of $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ we are taking? The book showed that $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ is a group under addition, multiplication as well as division (multiplication with the reciprocal) but it does not mention which operation we are taking for finding automorphisms. Furthermore, I cannot think of any automorphisms from this group to itself apart from the identity.
2. The book states that 'the automorphisms carry every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself.' I'm not sure what this means. Is the implication that every automorphism is essentially the identity function when applied on rational elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ or does it simply mean that every rational maps to another rational?
3. Finally, I do not understand why this group is referred to as $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\theta]/\mathbb{Q})$. What does the '/' represent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ are bijective homomorphisms from this field to itself; they form a group under function composition. Carrying every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself means that for every $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a \mapsto a$ under each of these automorphisms. The `/` represents that the "bottom" field is fixed in the way mentioned above.

Comment: @MorganRodgers An automorphism preserves both multiplication as well as addition?

Comment: To complete Morgan Rodgers’ comment, here are some examples: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has two automorphisms (over $\mathbb{Q}$), the identity and the complex conjugation. Similarly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has two automorphisms: the identity and $a+b\sqrt{2} \longmapsto a-b\sqrt{2}$ (check it!). You can even construct four automorphisms for $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$, for instance, has only one automorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$, the identity.

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data Page 106, Definition 2.3: "a homomorphism of both the additive group and the multiplicative monoid". So yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this for lack of context because all of these details are in the book, p. 106 for the definition of a ring homomorphism, and p. 234 for the meaning of $E/F$ in $\mathrm{Gal~}E/F$, as long as what it means for elements of $F$ to be "sent to themselves", also p. 234. (These page numbers taken from the 2nd edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ is isomorphic to a quotient ring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  In the case that $\theta$ is a zero of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ then we can factor that polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as $(x -\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$ where the $\alpha_i$ are the roots of the polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$.  An automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ that leaves $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed are obtained by permuting the $\alpha_i$.  Not all permutations will give an automorphism though!
2. Has been answered in the comments.
3. The $/\mathbb{Q}$ is just telling you that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the base field.  Sometimes there will be intermediate fields.  For instance if we have $K \subset L \subset F$ with these being fields then one can talk about $\mathrm{Gal(F/K)}$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(F/L)$.